# How to count words in specific column against matching words in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I want to be able to:

- extract specific words from *column1* in *Table1* - but only the words that are matched from *Table2* from a column called *word*,
- perform a(n individual) count of the number of words that have been found, and
- put this information into a permanent table with a format, that looks like:

**Final**

```
Word    | Count
--------+------
Test    |     7
Blue    |     5
Have    |     2
```

Currently I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO final (word, count) 
SELECT
  extext
  , SUM(dbo.WordRepeatedNumTimes(extext, 'test')) AS Count
FROM [dbo].[TestSite_Info], [dbo].[table_words]
WHERE [dbo].[TestSite_Info].ExText = [dbo].[table_words].Words
GROUP BY ExText;
```

The function dbo.WordRepeatedNumTimes is:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[WordRepeatedNumTimes]
(@SourceString varchar(8000),@TargetWord varchar(8000))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @NumTimesRepeated int
,@CurrentStringPosition int
,@LengthOfString int
,@PatternStartsAtPosition int
,@LengthOfTargetWord int
,@NewSourceString varchar(8000)

SET @LengthOfTargetWord = len(@TargetWord)
SET @LengthOfString = len(@SourceString)
SET @NumTimesRepeated = 0
SET @CurrentStringPosition = 0
SET @PatternStartsAtPosition = 0
SET @NewSourceString = @SourceString

WHILE len(@NewSourceString) >= @LengthOfTargetWord
  BEGIN
    SET @PatternStartsAtPosition = CHARINDEX (@TargetWord,@NewSourceString)
    IF @PatternStartsAtPosition <> 0
    BEGIN
      SET @NumTimesRepeated = @NumTimesRepeated + 1
      SET @CurrentStringPosition = @CurrentStringPosition + @PatternStartsAtPosition + 
        @LengthOfTargetWord
      SET @NewSourceString = substring(@NewSourceString, @PatternStartsAtPosition + 
        @LengthOfTargetWord, @LengthOfString)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @NewSourceString = ''
    END
  END
RETURN @NumTimesRepeated
END
```

---

When I run the above `INSERT` statement, no record is inserted.

In the table *TestSite_Info* is a column called *Extext*. Within this column, there is random text - one of the words being 'test'.
In the other table called *Table_Words*, I have a column called *Words* and one of the words in there is 'Test'. So in theory, as the word is a match, I would pick it up, put it into the table *Final*, and then next to the word (in another column) the count of how many times the word has been found within *TestSite_Info.Extext*.

**Table_Words**

```
id|word
--+----
1 |Test
2 |Onsite
3 |Here
4 |As
```

**TestSite_Info**

```
ExText
-------------------------------------------------
This is a test, onsite test , test test i am here
```

The expected *Final* table has been given at the top.

-- Update

Now that I have run Abecee block of code this actually works in terms of bringing back a count column and the id relating to the word.

Here are the results :

```
id|total
--+----
169 |3
170 |0
171 |5
172 |7
173 |1
174 |3
```

Taken from the following text which it is extracting from :

> Test test and I went to and this was a test I'm writing rubbish hello
>   but I don't care about care and care seems care to be the word that you will see appear
>   four times as well as word word word word word, but a .! 
>   who knows whats going on here.

So as you can see, the count for ID 172 appears 7 times (as a reference please see below to what ID numbers relate to in terms of words) which is incorrect it should appear appear 6 times (its added +1 for some reason) as well as ID 171 which is the word care, that appears 4 times but is showing up as 5 times on the count. Any ideas why this would be?
Also what I was really after was a way as you have quite kindly done of the table showing the ID and count BUT also showing the word it relates to as well in the final table, so I don't have to link back through the ID table to see what the actual word is.

```
Word|id
--+----
 as   |174
here  |173
word  |172
care  |171
hello |170
test  |169
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please consider to provide a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the test data, and your SQL statement, which does not quite deliver the expected result.

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? - And Yes: The quoted article might actuallly be relevant. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Abecee for your help. I actually have both 2 instances. If we could get it to run on SQL 2008 R2 that would be great, also SQL Serv 2012 Standard.

Comment: Hi Abecee, Absoultly Briliant its nearly there. I have run your following statement, but there are a couple of things still not adding up. I'll put the updated info now into the question field

Comment: Parse out the words into a separate table.

Comment: I'll jump back on this today and update. New Year is out the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work along the updated

```
WITH
Detail AS (
  SELECT
    W.id
    , W.word
    , T.extext
    , (LEN(REPLACE(T.extext, ' ', '  ')) + 2
      - LEN(REPLACE(' '
                    + UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(T.extext, ' ', '  '), ':', ' '), '.', ' '), ',', ' '))
                    + ' ', ' ' + UPPER(W.word) + ' ', '')) - 1
      ) / (LEN(W.word) + 2) count
  FROM Table_Words W
  JOIN TestSite_Info T
    ON CHARINDEX(UPPER(W.word), UPPER(T.extext)) > 0
)
INSERT INTO Result
SELECT
  id
  , SUM(count) total
FROM Detail
GROUP BY id
;
```

(Had forgotten to count in the blanks added to the front and the end, missed a sign change, and got mixed up as for the length of the word(s) surrounded by blanks. Sorry about that. Thanks for testing it more thoroughly than I did originally!)
Tested on SQL Server 2008: [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2625/1) and 2012: [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2625/1).
And [with your test case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/544fa6/4) as well.

It:

- is pure SQL (no UDF required),
- has room for some tuning:

  - Store words all lower / all upper case, unless case matters (Which would require to adjust the suggested solution.)
  - Store strings to check with all punctuation marks removed.

Please comment if and as further detail is required.

Comment: Abecee I've just added more detail to the orginal question of the result of your script you have created. Its nearly there but still a small bit off

Comment: Quick check basically confirmed your findings. Sorry. Need to get a closer look. - I guess, Oracle is no option?  ;-)

Comment: Thanks Abecee for that No it has to be in SQL ;)

Comment: Hi Abecee, any luck your end?

Comment: Hi Darris. Sorry - can't really work on it at this time.

Comment: Hey Abecee, no worries at all, I'm playing around with the spaces at the moment of your original code. Still cant crack it! ;)

Comment: Hi Abecee, Thanks very much for the code. So i have tried it, it does count the words but a few small things which are critical still with the issues. For example if the word 'as' is a word to match it will find it but it picks it up one extra time for some strange reason, i think this might be because there is a letter 'a' by itself but will test. Its so nearly there!! I do like though the first one you did with the LEN and REPLACE, This one is also nearly there and i'm just trying with shorting some of the spaces to get a more accurate count.

Comment: Hi Abecee, Is there a way to get an exact match on the word, what's happening is for example the word Christmas is in fact picking up the the word 'as' as well. So the LIKE operator is more in use than an exact = to the word if that makes sense

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce "Christmas" picking up "as". Made sure right from the beginning, the opposite not to be the case (e.g. counting "Christmas" towards "as"). Could only imagine something like this to come up when playing tricks using special character sets, if at all. Double checked: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43b55/1) Could you, please, modify the Fiddle to demonstrate the effect? (BTW: Are you using the code as updated yesterday? - But even the code provided earlier should not fail in this particular respect.)

Comment: Abecee, Happy New Year!! After through-er testing, i have found the code you have written is the closest to getting the word count correct. I have tried to create a SQL Fiddle with a much larger amount of Text but it does not allow me, but if you could INSERT the text from the following   URL   http://www.dailymail.co.uk/wires/index.html  into the textcolumn to be counted against the words table and Word being 'Recovery' - I get a count of 7 when really it is 9. Also for example the word united should be 14 but comes back as 12.Any fixes on this would be fantastic! Thanks

Comment: The other small thing I noticed is that it picks up words that are like a word but counts it as '0' for example surge and the word is surgey, this is OK but it would be good if we got a count of 1 for these ones. I have played and played with the special characters but seem to make it worse, if you are able to improve that would be great.

Comment: Happy New Year to you, too! (i) Regarding the current version of the Daily Mail page: It has one instance of `'Recovery` (with a single quotation mark right in front of it). To count this one as well, either the list of special characters in `UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(T.extext, ' ', '  '), ':', ' '), '.', ' '), ',', ' '))` must be extended, or the text pre-processed to get rid of any such special characters. (Regex could help in Oracle SQL, but not SQL Server.) (ii) Do I get you right: You have "surge" in the word list, and want it to count occurences of "surgey"? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi Abecee, Yes that is correct, Surge was one example, basically in the Search text it was Surgery.What the result came back with was a '0' on the count column and when i counted manually the word was not there but a variation of the word. There has been some words that have shown once when checked manually and count was '0' . I think this is down to special characters again.

Comment: As/if you are controlling the word list, you could supply a list of to be checked variants. On that basis, it might be possible. With no such assistance, I see no realistic chance of satisfying such a requirement. - Just take your example, both "surgery" and "surge" are valid English words. If you had both of them in your initial world list - how would a simple word count decide, which bucket to use for which occurence?

Comment: If it works for you, please, consider to  actually [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. And possibly [vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) for it as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand, this might do the job. However, things will be more clear if you post the schema

```
create table final(
  word varchar(100),
  count integer
);

insert into final (word, count) 
select column1, count(*)
from table1, table2
where table1.column1 = table2.words
group by column1;
```

Comment: @darrisford: You should actually update your question in order to include all aspects, which are relevant to your problem.

Comment: @darrisford: The quoted article http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/counting-instances-word-record is most likely of limited applicability to your question. But you might want to provide the original data to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the problem description, the presented `SELECT` seems to try to align/join full "exText" strings with individual "words" - but based on equality. Then, it has "exText" in the `SELECT` list whilst "Result" seems to wait for individual words. (That would not fail the `INSERT`, though, as long as the field is not guarded by a foreign key constraint. But as the `WHERE`/`JOIN` is not likely to let any data through, this is probably never coming up as an issue anyway.)
For an alternative to the pure declarative approach, you might want to try along

```
INSERT INTO final (word, count)
SELECT
  word
  , SUM(dbo.WordRepeatedNumTimes(extext, word)) AS Count
FROM [dbo].[TestSite_Info], [dbo].[table_words]
WHERE  CHARINDEX(UPPER([dbo].[table_words].Word), UPPER([dbo].[TestSite_Info].ExText)) > 0
GROUP BY word;
```

<sub>You have "Word" in your "Table_Words" description - but use "[dbo].[table_words].Words" in your `WHERE` condition…</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.
The best approach for this solution was :

WITH
Detail AS (
  SELECT
    W.id
    , W.word
    , T.extext
    , (LEN(REPLACE(T.extext, ' ', '  ')) + 2
      - LEN(REPLACE(' '
                    + UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(T.extext, ' ', '  '), ':', ' '), '.', ' '), ',', ' '))
                    + ' ', ' ' + UPPER(W.word) + ' ', '')) - 1
      ) / (LEN(W.word) + 2) count
  FROM Table_Words W
  JOIN TestSite_Info T
    ON CHARINDEX(UPPER(W.word), UPPER(T.extext)) > 0
)
INSERT INTO Result
SELECT
  id
  , SUM(count) total
FROM Detail
GROUP BY id